# Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data

Tags: localhost

I'm ready to give up. I've spent the entire week trying to get a Joomla site to run on localhost. I can get to phpmyadmin. Please help me.

If I change $database to none, I receive this error:
Error: Failed to start application: Could not connect to MySQL server.

What I've tried:
Removed .htaccess
Changed url to 127.0.0.1
Reinstalled joomla
Checked  permissions in phmyadmin and win 11
I'm running wamp  as administrator

Details:
Joomla 3.9.19
PHP  7.2.34
Wamp, Win 11

Configuration.php

```
public $host = 'http://localhost/';
public $user = 'root';
public $password = '';
public $db = 'com_pathwayplanner';
public $dbprefix = 'b9iu2_';
public $live_site = '';
public $session_handler = 'database';
```

Comment: How did you install Joomla if it can't connect to the database?

Comment: Have you tried using `localhost` as database host?

Comment: As in the previous comment, I have just $host = 'localhost'; You could try and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Sharky, after installation I imported an existing website. And yes, Sharky and Robbie, I've tried localhost as database host.